# C#: Split string on date keeping date intact

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following sample data:

```
21/10/2012 blahblah blah blahblah 265 blah 25 22/10/2012 blahblah blah blahblah 10 blah 14 blah 66 NK blahblah blah blahblah 25
```

I want the output to be the following data:

```
21/10/2012 blahblah blah blahblah 265 blah 25
22/10/2012 blahblah blah blahblah 10 blah 14 blah 66 NK blahblah blah blahblah 25
```

I have tried the following:

```
var regex = new Regex ("(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{4})");
var matches = regex.Matches(str);//str is given above
foreach(var item in matches)
{
  //my logic to do operations
}
```

This gives the array of dates. How can I split the string on dates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split your string on empty string before the date. For that you need this regex:

```
string[] arr = Regex.split(str, "(?<!\d)(?=\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4})");
```

Splitting on the above regex, will give you the output you want. It will split your string on the empty string which is preceded by date of the form - `21/10/2012`, and not preceded by a `digit`. We need to do the `look-behind` stuff, so that it doesn't tear the day part apart. Without that, it will split on the empty string before `1` in `21`, thus keeping `2` and `1/10/2012` as separate element.

Also, note that you will get an `empty string` as the first element of your array, since the first empty string in your string satisfies the split criteria.

---

Validating dates can get complex with regex. Specially, if you want to restrict every possible invalid date, like `30 Feb`. But still, if you want you can try out this regex, but it will match *30 & 31 Feb* and even *31 November*.

```
string[] arr = Regex.split(str, "(?<!\\d)(?=(?:0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][01])/(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])/(?:19[0-9]{2}|2[0-9]{3}))");
```

Comment: It also validates dates like 35/36/2012

Comment: @BhushanFirake. For capturing a valid date, you would have to build a different regex, which would be a complex one. Using only valid digits in character class instead of `\d`.

Comment: @BhushanFirake. Updated regex, you can try it out.